# Manage Ignite cluster via s3 DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain()

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ignite

Is it possible to create an s3 managed ignite cluster using DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain?  In java you can do it like this:

```
    DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain chain = new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain();
    AWSCredentials creds = chain.getCredentials();
```

I know I can easily create a wrapper class that Implements [AWSCredentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentials.html) and uses the provider chain under the hood, like in here http://apacheignite.gridgain.org/docs/aws-config.  Is there a way to do this just with spring? Without the wrapper?

Edit:  Here is probably what Im going to use:

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain;

/**
 * Created by Carlos Bribiescas on 10/28/16.
 */
public class DefaultAWSCredentials implements AWSCredentials{
    private DefaultAWSCredentials() {}

    private static class LazyHolder{
        private static AWSCredentials CREDENTIALS = new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain().getCredentials();
    }

    @Override
    public String getAWSAccessKeyId() {
        return LazyHolder.CREDENTIALS.getAWSAccessKeyId();
    }

    @Override
    public String getAWSSecretKey() {
        return LazyHolder.CREDENTIALS.getAWSSecretKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to utilize Spring `factory-bean` and `factory-method` for this:

```
<bean id="aws.cred.chain" class="com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain"/>

<property name="ipFinder">
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.s3.TcpDiscoveryS3IpFinder">
        <property name="awsCredentials">
            <bean factory-bean="aws.cred.chain" factory-method="getCredentials"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
</property>
```